# How to perform full text search in django?

Tags: django, django-views

For example i have a title `How to use User Model in Django` and I search with keyword only `django` then it returns all the titles which has django which is fine but when i enter a keyword like `django user model` then it returns none.How can I solve this

Any help would be appreciated

views.py

```
def search_blogs(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    if q:
        blogs = Blog.objects.filter(title__icontains=q).order_by('-created')
        return render(request,'blog/search_blogs.html',{"blogs":blogs,'q':q})
    else:
        messages.error(request,'Please enter some keyword to search')
        return redirect('blog:blogs')
```

template

```
<form action="{% url 'blog:search_blog' %}" class="search-form">                
<input type="text" name="q"  placeholder="Search blogs" align="center" >
 <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn-sm btn-info >
</form>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
q = request.GET.get('q')
    if q:
        words = request.GET.get('q').split(" ")
        q_filters = Q()
        for word in words:
            q_filters |= Q(title__icontains=word)

        blogs = Blog.objects.filter(q_filters)
        return render(request, 'blog/search_blogs.html', {"blogs": blogs, 'q': words})
    else:
        messages.error(request,'Please enter some keyword to search')
        return redirect('blog:blogs')
```

Now in the updated code space is also an input for filter.For example.If I searched `user model in django` then it returns the other result also which has space but no other title matching only *space*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `Q` and combine multiple `__contains` together:

```
blogs = Blog.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains="word one") | Q(title__icontains="word two"))
```

You can use a for loop to generate enough filters:

```
words = request.GET.get('q', '').split(" ")
q_filters = Q()

for word in words:
    q_filters |= Q(title__icontains=word)

blogs = Blog.objects.filter(q_filters)
```

But if you use PostgreSQL as your database, you can take a look here:

[Django docs: Full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/)

Comment: one problem with this is if I pass an empty query it also displays results and the result has all lists .

Comment: Well, empty query means no filter and it makes sense if it results in returning all rows. But you can change the behavior with a little code.

Comment: i've attached my update into my question but one problem is it is taking _space_ as an query parameter also.

Comment: You could create a validation function and validate the string based on its length, language and anything else you might need.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Postgres, Django provides you support for fulltext search. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/search/

For a high-level overview of searching, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/search/.

If you need more robust fulltext search you can use Elasticsearch. There are plenty of ways how to integrate Django. For instance [django-haystack](https://haystacksearch.org/) app or [Elasticsearch DSL library](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)